# How do I add external images to a map using the Nokia Here Map Image API?

Tags: here-api

Thanks in advance. I'm trying to figure out how to add client faces (images) to certain locations on a map using the Nokia Here Map Image API.

I am able to do this via the Javascript API, but unfortunately I also need to be able to download an image for use in a generated PDF file, and I can't figure out how to add external images to the map.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly understand your requirement but if you want to convert the canvas which shows the map to an Image, you can do that with the map caprutre event, something like following should work

```
map.capture(function(canvas) {
                if (canvas) {

                     var img = new Image();
                     img.src = canvas.toDataURL("img/jpeg");
                     window.open(img.src);


                } else {
                    // For example when map is in Panorama mode
                    alert('Capturing is not supported');
                }
              }, [ui], 0, 0, document.getElementById("mapContainer").offsetWidth, document.getElementById("mapContainer").offsetHeight);
```

Comment: Thank you Jithin; that might help, but I'd have to figure out how to run some javascript server-side in order to use that properly. Ultimately, I will have a scheduled task that generate a series of PDF files (with map images on them) to send out via email. So this won't be happening in a web browser, hence why ideally I would use the Map Image API via REST.

Comment: Unfortunately the Image or Tile API do not seem provide an option to add external images. Maybe use Node.js for serverside Javascripting ?

Comment: Thanks, Jithin; that does seem to be the only/best option available.